# Apache CXF Client Not getting Invoked

Tags: cxf

I am new to Apache CXF , so please help .
I dont know why the client is not getting called . 
client = (BayerService) factory.create();

I did this way

```
public class RunBayer implements CallbackHandler
{

RunBayer()
{
 init();
}

  private static void init()
   {
      JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
      WSS4JOutInterceptor out = new WSS4JOutInterceptor();
      out.setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
      out.setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "svi_ws");
      out.setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, "PasswordDigest");
      factory.getOutInterceptors().add(out);
      factory.setServiceClass(BayerService.class);
      factory.setAddress(host);
      client = (BayerService) factory.create();
   }

}
```

And I have a BayerService interface which is in this format

```
public interface BayerService
{
 public OurServiceResponse OurView(@WebParam(name = "request") ServiceRequest request);
}
```

**I have another class named Bayer.java which actually implements this Interafce**

```
public class Bayer implements BayerService
{

public OurServiceResponse OurView(ServiceRequest request)
{
// code 
}

}
```

Could anybody please tell me why the control is not coming inside when i call this way ??

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the code like below in your RunBayer class.

```
client.OurView(request);
```